# Updating Data and Reloading the CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am attempting to update a data object that holds the data for my collectionView (simply just filtering the data model), and the wishing to reload the collectionView with the filtered data. The issue is upon reloading the collectionView I am getting and error indexPath out of range when the reload happens. Seems when debugging that the collectionView is attempting to reload the original dataObject, not the filtered one. What am I doing wrong:

```
func handleFilterAction(sender: FilterButton){
    guard let type = sender.buttonFilterType else {return}
    switch type {
    case .FilterAll:
        return
    case .FilterDay:
        return
    case .FillterWeek:
        return
    case .FilterMonth:
        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ 
            let objects = FilterDataManager.filterDataWith(currentLocalData: &self.eventObjects, filterOption: .ThisMonth)
            self.eventObjects.removeAll()
            self.eventObjects = objects
        }, completion: { (completion) in
            self.navigationItem.title = "This Month"
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    }

    self.handleShowFilterView()

}
```

The eventObjects is what the collectionView should be reading for the data:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventObjects[section].sectionObjects.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `performBatchUpdates` when you want to animate the changes to the `collectionView`.  iOS expects you to make calls to methods such as `collectionView?.insertItems(at: [IndexPath])` and
`collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath])` to let it know what you are inserting and deleting so that it can animate it.  For both of these calls, you pass in an array of all of the `IndexPath`s being inserted or deleted.

When you do this, iOS has expectations for the number of items that are now in the `collectionView`.  The formula is:

```
newItemCount = previousItemCount - deletedItemCount + insertedItemCount
```

In your case, you modified your *model*, but you never called the `insertItems` and `deleteItems` methods, so iOS still thinks all of the items are there.  It is this disconnect between your *model* and the `collectionView` that is causing your problem.

To fix this, you need to do one of the following:

1. Call `deleteItems` and `insertItems` with the array of `IndexPath`s that you are deleting and inserting (call delete first).
2. Or, forget about `performBatchUpdates` and just update your model data and call  `reloadData`.

Also, make sure `numberOfSections` is returning `eventObjects.count`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, So I removed the performBatchUpdates() call and am now simply just calling the reloadData() after the updates are performed on the model, but still getting the same errror, when debugging I am noticing that the model is updated with data, and the first section is seen correctly, but it seems that it is still expecting a second section.

Comment: and the updated object model only has one since the filtering.

Comment: Were you expecting the filtering to leave data for just one section?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `FilterDataManager`.  Perhaps you need to call it separately for each section.  Something like `for sectionNum in eventObjects.indices { var data = eventObjects[sectionNum]; let objects = FilterDataManager.filterDataWith(currentLocalData: &data, filterOption: .ThisMonth); eventsObjects[sectionNum] = objects }`.

Comment: Also, make sure the `numberOfSections` function is returning `eventsObjects.count`.

Comment: haha silly me yeah that was the issue, the numberOfSections was the issue, it was referencing another object that had the incorrect count. I updated it, and working perfectly.... Thanks for all the help!~  :)